# Объединить тексты в строках с одинаковым идентификатором

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть таблица с двумя колонками: в первой - 'id', во второй  - строка текста.

Необходимо строки с одинаковым `id` объединить через запятую.
[image]

Вот так примерно, автоматически, так как строк больше 30 тысяч.

Собственно, нужна формула, если это возможно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылка на таблицы (изначальная разделена на блоки по 10 тысяч записей). https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14o0ALY1rxbicDFHNzl5bHF06Dzto1V5t?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сортировать данные по столбцу с `ID`. По возрастанию, по убыванию - неважно.

Цель: сбор одинаковых `ID` в блоки.

2. В ячейку `D2` (и протянутить по строкам):

   `=ЕСЛИ(A2=A1;D1&","&B2;B2)`

Цель: объединение данных столбца В. Все данные для одного `ID` будут собраны в строке с последним упоминанием `ID`.

3. В ячейку `E2` (и протянуть по строкам):

   `=--(A2<>A3)`

Цель: определение строк с последним упоминанием `ID` (эти строки отмечаются единицей).

4. Скрыть столбцы `B:C`, фильтр по столбцу `E`.

Цель: оставить видимыми только нужные данные.

5. Копировать данные столбцов `A` и `D`, вставить на другой лист.

Цель: получить таблицу с неповторяющимися `ID` и их данными.

---

*На 9 000 строк вариант отработал довольно шустро, данные `ID` с максимальным количеством (85 строк) объединились без проблем в строку длиной 5572 символа*